# Running a sudo command on startup

Tags: macos, sudo

I want to run `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias someIp` every time I open my mac, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a LauchDaemon. LaunchDaemons are processes managed by the launchd service in macOS that are loaded when the system boots. LaunchDaemons can be used to run a program one-time, contiuously or periodically after boot.

Create a file called `org.my.ifconfig.plist` in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`
with the following content and you should be good to go.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.my.ifconfig</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/sbin/ifconfig</string>
      <string>lo0</string>
      <string>alias</string>
      <string>someIp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Make sure the file is owned by `root` and in the group `wheel`, and has the permissions `644`: Owner – read/write, group – read, everyone – read

More information can be found at developer.apple.com at [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Comment: Mind the typo: `<interger>10</integer>` -> `<integer>10</integer>`